# Content.once is not a function

Tags: buffer, ipfs

I try to push a file to the IPFS, and I have converted to the Buffer. I got this error " content.once is not a function".
I am using this library in node.

```
var Buffer = require('buffer/').Buffer;
const doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML('test',10,10);
var covnertedBuffer = Buffer.from(doc.output('arraybuffer');
```

Then, I take the convertedBuffer and pass it to the IPFS api.

Any idea?

Updated test:

I have successfully pushed a file to the IPFS via the API with this code below.

```
const filename = '/home/administrator/Downloads/5HP8LWKHLV.pdf';
 this.ipfsApi = ipfsApi('localhost', '5001');
    let readablestream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
    readablestream.on('readable', () => {
      let result = readablestream.read();
      console.log(result);
      if (result) {
        this.ipfsApi.files.add(result, function(err, files) {
          if (err) {
            res.json('err');
            console.log(err);
          }
          res.json(files);
        });
      }
    });
```

But, when I get the arrayBuffer from the doc.output and convert to the Buffer object and push to the IPFS and it failed. Please see below.

```
 var _buffer = Buffer.from(req.buffer);
    console.log('Converted to buffer:' + _buffer);
    this.ipfsApi = ipfsApi('localhost', '5001');
    this.ipfsApi.files.add(_buffer, function(err, files) {
      if (!err) {
        res.status(500);
        console.log(err);
      } else {

        res.json(files);
        res.status(200);
      }
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: What is content? It likely isn't what you think it is. That is an eventemitter.

Comment: @DanD. - I have updated above. Any clues?

Comment: The first method I pas in with the physical file and it works fine, the second method I just pass in the arraybuffer generated from the doc.output('arraybuffer') and convert it to the Buffer object. The IPFS add method returns with the undefined object but the hash key.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Buffer.from(your_buffer) to your buffer before doing ipfs push works.

```
ipfs.files.add(Buffer.from(put_your_buffer_here), (error, result) => {
      if(error) {
        console.error(error)
        return
      }
      console.log("upload is successful");

  });
```

Comment: It works. I don't know why it is not accepted. +1

Comment: Thanks @Sanyifejű